# Annotate images in FFMPEG and then convert to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Am fairly new to FFMPEG. I am able to convert a sequence of images to video, with each image displayed for a specified time .
I want to annotate these images ,e.g with text, and then convert to video.
I don't know weather it's feasible using FFMPEG or not. I want to:

- give ffmpeg a text file having list of images to be encoded to video and there duration.
- If any of these images need to be annotated with text, then that informatiom. Be able to specify styling of the text (font,font-size,shadow,color,hightlight etc)
- image annotation (overlaying image over another image).
- create video.

Answer (score 2):

As described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623676/text-on-video-ffmpeg you can use the **drawtext** filter for this.

Documentation:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext

See the more complex example for showing text for s specific time only:
Show text fading in and out (appearing/disappearing):

```
#!/bin/sh
DS=1.0 # display start
DE=10.0 # display end
FID=1.5 # fade in duration
FOD=5 # fade out duration
ffplay -f lavfi "color,drawtext=text=TEST:fontsize=50:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:fontcolor_expr=ff0000%{eif\\\\: clip(255*(1*between(t\\, $DS + $FID\\, $DE - $FOD) + ((t - $DS)/$FID)*between(t\\, $DS\\, $DS + $FID) + (-(t - $DE)/$FOD)*between(t\\, $DE - $FOD\\, $DE) )\\, 0\\, 255) \\\\: x\\\\: 2 }"
```